# Replace shortest string match in bash

Tags: string, bash

In bash, there are several useful string manipulation patterns, such as removing shortest/longest substring from beginning/end of the string:

```
${var#substring}
${var##substring}
${var%substring}
${var%%substring}
```

Then there is also the replacement pattern, that replaces a substring from any part of the string:

```
${var/substring/replacement}
```

The problem with this is that it is greedy and always replaces the longest match. For example if I have a directory name like `/a/b/foo-bar/x/y/z` and I want to replace any subdirectory name starting with *foo-* to *baz*, then it won't work as I expect. I expect the result to be `/a/b/baz/x/y/z`. I tried the following command:

```
${PWD/\/foo-*\///baz/}
```

The result in this case is `/a/b/baz/z`, because the pattern matches the longest substring starting with `/foo-` and ending with `/`. Is there any way to get the correct result without calling `sed` or any other external string manipulation program?

Answer (score 4):

Of course, you can always use extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob

var=/a/b/foo-bar/x/y/z/foo-bar2/1/2/3
echo "${var//\/foo-*([^\/])\///baz/}"
```

will happily output

```
/a/b/baz/x/y/z/baz/1/2/3
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure BASH you can do this (using BASH regex capabilities):

```
s='/a/b/foo-bar/x/y/z'
p="$s"
[[ "$s" =~ ^(.*/)'foo-'[^/]*(.*)$ ]] && p="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}baz${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

echo "$p"
/a/b/baz/x/y/z
```

Comment: Beware that this fails if the variable doesn't contain the string `foo`. To fix this you have to add some tests, and eventually it becomes more awkward than extglobs! `:)`.

Comment: Ok I updated the answer to make sure assignment happens ONLY when `foo-` is there in the original string.

Comment: And before the regex you probably need `p=$s` so that when `s` doesn't match, `p` automatically expands to `s`.

Comment: Also, this only performs one replacement: if `s='/a/b/foo-bar/x/y/z/foo-bar2/1/2/3'` then only the first `foo-bar` is replaced.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yes that's right, to make multiple replacements a loop is required here and for that `extglob` is better option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it in pure Bash that replaces *all* subdirectories in the path that match the pattern. It splits the path into an array, does the replacement on each path component into a new array, and then uses `printf` to replace the path separators.

```
name='/a/b/foo-bar/x/foo-y/z';
IFS=$'/';
aname=($name);
bname=();
for i in "${aname[@]}";
do bname+=("${i/foo-*/baz}");done;
printf -v newname "%s/" "${bname[@]}";

printf "%s\n" "$newname"
```

**output**

```
/a/b/baz/x/baz/z/
```

(Sorry about all the `;`s, I just did a quick copy & paste from the shell)

Comment: To split on slashes, you could use this: `IFS=/ read -r -d '' -a aname < <(printf '%s\0' "$name")`. This preserves all the characters (spaces, newlines, etc.) and is pathname-extension-safe. Then, to perform the replacement without a loop: `bname=( "${aname[@]/foo-*/baz}")`. In fact you can get along with just these two lines: `IFS=/ read -r -d '' -a aname < <(printf '%s\0' "$name"); ( IFS=/; printf '%s\n' "${aname[*]/foo-*/baz}" )`. It will only fail if `name` has a trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks, @gniourf_gniourf. I didn't know you could do `"${aname[*]/foo-*/baz}"`; that's neat! And I must confess that I didn't even think of using `read`... the `-a` option must've slipped my mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use regex in bash's built-in string substitution. If you have to stick to the built-in string manipulation, you have to extract the substring `foo-bar` first then use it in your `${PWD/$match/baz}`.

You can do it very easily however, if you could use regex. There are a lot of handy string handlers under linux/unix, could do that very easily. sed for example:

```
kent$  sed 's#/foo-[^/]*#/baz#' <<< '/a/b/foo-bar/x/y/z'
/a/b/baz/x/y/z
```